# Methods for merged site root with modular Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a Node.js server which implements a set of base files that I want to serve as a default.  Then other users of the server can require() it and overload some defaults and perhaps add additional files.  For example:

```
server_base
  /site
    -> index.html 'A' 
    -> images 'A'
        -> icon.jpg

user_server (requiring server_base)
  /site
    -> index.html 'B'
    -> images 'B'
        -> picture.jpg
```

The resulting website would have the merged set of those files with the user's index.html taking precedence over the base.

So far I've been trying to accomplish this with express since the use() method should allow for this hierarchy to be established.

server_base.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = module.exports = express(),
    server = null;

app.configure( function() {
    server = require('http').createServer(app);
    app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/site'));
    server.listen(80);
});
```

user_site.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    sb = require('../server_base');

app.configure( function() {
    app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/site'));
    app.use(sb); // server_base configure occurs here
});
```

As I understand it, if express finds a requested file in the first referenced root path (user_site's in this case) it should return that file.  If not and its found in the other path, it should return that file (server_base).  What I'm seeing though is that the '/' path is being totally wiped out with whatever the second call to use('/', ...) provided.

I figured perhaps it was the configure() call occurring twice and effectively wiping out settings.  So I then tried exporting from server_base it's site path so that the user_site would app.use(...) it's own path followed by the server_base's.  This results in a site somehow unable to serve any files.

I'm pretty new to Node.js and Express so if there is a better/cleaner way to make an easily-distributable and extendable server_base, I'm open to alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the middlewares is important. You need to make your server base add it's static handler after the user has had time to add its static handler, something like this:

user_site.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    sb = require('./server_base');

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/site'));
sb(app); // server_base configure occurs here

app.listen(8080);
```

server_base.js:

```
var express = require('express');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/site'));
  return app;
};
```

Comment: I don't follow what you're saying.  `app` won't have a method called `static` (at least it doesn't when I tried what you've stated).  Also it looks like you're suggesting I configure the user's path before calling use(sb) which is what I already stated I tried (though from within configure()).  Would please explain further what you're suggesting?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't easy to follow that code ;) I changed the example to a working explanation of what I mean.

Comment: Thanks; I thought that might be what you were describing.  This worked great!